# How to work on remote machine from jenkins without adding as a slave or How to add slave through url?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have to run some jobs from a website.
Jenkins is the best solution for it.
But we have to run the jobs on the users machine with the users id.
For this we need to add users linux machine as slave or Is there any plugin through which we can do ssh on users machine and do all the processes?

I thought of using swarm plugin but swarm dependencies jar need to be run from the user's machine. Again we need to do ssh on user's machine to run the jar.

Answer (score 0):

See the [SSH plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin):

> This Plugin was derived from the very cool [SCP Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCP+plugin).
>
> You can use the SSH Plugin to run shell commands on a remote machine via ssh.